# Friggeri CV: Reduce space between entry

Tags: spacing, friggeri-cv

In the [Friggeri CV Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/friggeri-cv-template/hmnchbfmjgqh) I'd like to reduce the spacing between entries in one `entrylist` (not all of them) but I really don't know how.

I'd like to reduce the spacing where the red arrows are on the attached screenshot.

[image]

My idea was to have two `\begin{entrylist}` in on section and that one of them has an attribute to reduce the spacing. But I don't know how to achieve that.

Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please explain better what you want, for example can you add an screeenshot and mark there what you want to change? And it would be very helpful, you could add an short compilable tex code resulting in your issue ...

Comment: Sorry I was a bit in a rush :) I added more details but I'm afraid I wouldn't know which part of the code to add here :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without MWE I have to guess a little bit but please see the following MWE for a possible solution.

You need to define a new command `\myentry` to get the smaller space not for all entries like:

```
\newcommand{\myentry}[4]{% <============================================
  #1&\parbox[t]{12.8cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4%\vspace{\parsep}% <==============================================
  }\\}
```

Please see that I simply commented out `\vspace{\parsep}` to get a smaller space ...

Add this code into the preamble to the CV code like:

```
 \documentclass[]{cv-style}

\sethyphenation[variant=british]{english}{} % Add words between the {} to avoid them to be cut 

\newcommand{\myentry}[4]{% <============================================
  #1&\parbox[t]{12.8cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4%\vspace{\parsep}% <==============================================
  }\\}


\begin{document}

\header{John}{Smith}           % Your name
\lastupdated

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SIDEBAR SECTION  -- In the aside, each new line forces a line break
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{aside}
%
\section{contact}
123 Broadway
City, State 050022
Country
~
+0 (000) 111 1111
+0 (000) 111 1112
~
john@smith.com
%
\section{languages}
English mother tongue
Spanish fluency
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
\end{aside}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{skills}
  \vspace{-0.2cm}

Skill 1, skill 2, skill 3, skill 4, skill 5.


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{education}

\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2010--2011}
{M.Sc. {\normalfont in Economics [Grade]}}
{University}
{\vspace{-0.3cm}}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2004--2009}
{B.Eng. {\normalfont in Engineering Management [Grade]}}
{University}
{(Emphasis in ...)}
%------------------------------------------------
\end{entrylist}

\section{myeducation}

\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\myentry
{2010--2011}
{M.Sc. {\normalfont in Economics [Grade]}}
{University}
{\vspace{-0.3cm}}
%------------------------------------------------
\myentry
{2004--2009}
{B.Eng. {\normalfont in Engineering Management [Grade]}}
{University}
{(Emphasis in ...)}
%------------------------------------------------
\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

Please see that I added a copy of section `education` called `myeducation` and used there the new command `\myentry`. Please see the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting cv]

Comment: Amazing ❤️ exactly the expected result. Please receive all my gratitude! I'll try to understand your code perfectly to be able to reproduce such kind of behaviour.